# Was more information that necessary given in this exercise?

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic, group-homomorphism

I had the following exercise in an exam:

**Question**

> Let $L$ be a first order language with equality, a binary function symbol, and a  binary predicate symbol.
>
> Let $I=(\Bbb Z, +, \leq), J=(\Bbb Z^2,+, \leq_{\Bbb Z^2})$ be two interpretations of $L$, where:
>
> $$(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)\\
> (a,b)\leq (c,d) \iff a<c \text{ or } (a =c \wedge b\leq d) $$
>   Decide whether $I\simeq J$.

**Attempt**

If $f:\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z^2$ is an isomorphism is must have the property: $f(n)=nf(1)\forall n$.

Proof:

If $n=0$:
$$f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0) \rightarrow f(0)=2f(0)\rightarrow f(0)=0=0\cdot f(1)$$.

$$f(n+1)=f(n)+f(1)=nf(1)+f(1)=(n+1)f(1)$$

The proving $f(-a)=-f(a)$ gives the property for all integers.

Then I said that as $f$ is bijective, $(1,0)$ must have a preimage, so there's some $k: f(k)=(1,0)$ but $f(k)=kf(1)=(ka,kb)=(1,0)\implies kb=0$ and I also have that $k\neq 0$ as $f(0)=\vec 0$. So $b= 0$ . I then did the same with the point $(0,1)$ and concluded $f(1)=(0,0)$, which is absurd because $f$ was bijective. Therefore $I\not \simeq J$.

Is this proof ok? I keep wondering if it is because I never used relation $\leq$ for anything.

Comment: Are you sure that if $f \colon \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}^2$ is an isomorphism, it must have the property $f(n) = n\,f(1) \ \forall n\,$? What is $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}^2\,$?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco I added a proof, $f$ preserving $+$ forces that to be true.

Comment: It is likely that you are to prove that $I$ and $J$ are not elementarly equivalent.

Comment: Does $\simeq$ mean isomorphism or does it mean elementary equivalence here?

Comment: @RobArthan Isomorphism.

Comment: @RobArthan I did have a typo. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are right, of course, sorry! I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment, $\simeq$ in your question denotes isomorphism. This means that you have been given too much information:

The two group structures are not isomorphic because  $\Bbb{Z}^2$ is not a cyclic group while $\Bbb{Z}$ is.

The two order structures are not isomorphic because with the lexicographic ordering there are elements $x, y \in \Bbb{Z}^2$ such that there are infinitely many $z \in \Bbb{Z}^2$ with $x < z < y$, but for $x, y \in \Bbb{Z}$ this cannot happen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that looks OK. You may want to be a little more specific about how you conclude $f(0)=(0,0)$, since $0$ is not a symbol of the language.

The two structures are so different that it is okay only to use part of them to conclude that they are not isomorphic. Conversely, you could also prove this looking only at $\le$ and ignoring $+$, such as by observing that even though $\le_I$ and $\le_J$ are both total orders, $J$ has a downwards closed proper nonempty subset with no maximal element, and $I$ doesn't.

Comment: I added a bit more info on how I proved that. Could you elaborate a bit more on how to prove this via the ordering? I think that to prove it that way I should show a formula which expresses that property of $J$, and show that it is valid in $J$ and not in $I$?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: No, the property of $J$ that $I$ lacks doesn't need to be expressible as a first-order formula. That would be the case if you wanted to show that the structures are _elementarily inequivalent_, but isomorphism is a stronger criterion then elementary equivalence, and therefore it is _easier_ to show something is _not_ isomorphic.

Comment: Is there a theorem that guarantees $I\not \simeq J$ if $J$ has some property that $I$ lacks? I haven't yet learned about that. The only one we were taught is that if $I\simeq J$ then $\forall \alpha \space I\vdash \alpha \iff J\vdash \alpha$.